# waiting for multiple images to load before sliding div down

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load several images into a div named 'images', when they finish loading I want it to slidedown the div 'images' which will show the actual images that have just been loaded into it, and I'm having a little bit of trouble writing out exactly how to make that happen.

This is what I have so far, it's not quite right:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var image=$('#images');

    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/home.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images");
    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/inventory.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images");
    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/services.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images");

    if (image.get(0).complete) { image.slideDown(300); } 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen for image `load` event. In the event handler count images and if the number of loaded images matches the toal number of requested images then start the show.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsGHY/

```
var imgCount = 0;
var image=$('#images');
$('#button').click(function() {
    console.log("Loading...");

    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/home.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);
    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/inventory.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);
    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/services.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images").load(onImage);

});

function onImage(e)
{
    console.log("Image loaded");
    imgCount++;

    if (imgCount == image.children().length)
    {
        image.slideDown(3000);
    }
}
```

`.load(function name)` means that we are attaching an event listener which will listen for `load` event and once it happens the function will be executed.

`onLoad(e){}` means that the function named `onLoad` takes one argument - this argument is passed from event listener and it is an `event` object.
Inside the function the `e` can be used to detect the object which trigerred the event, to gater some date an more...

Comment: I've seen this a bunch of times and can't figure out what it means, when you have function onImage(e) what is the 'e'?

Comment: the other thing is there are multiple buttons that do this, so does the two variables at the top being outside of the click even become a problem in that situation?

Comment: For your first question please see my edit. I am not sure if I understand correctly the second question.

Comment: actually sorry, no this doesn't seem to work in mobile safari on ios but it does on my computer in chrome, not sure why

Comment: It seems to work on my iPad and iPhone. It seems jsfiddle in generl is not working. Try this URL: http://jsbin.com/iquzoy/1/

Comment: for some reason I just can't get this to work on my iphone, but it works fine on the computer.  Your demo works fine on the phone, just my implementation some how doesn't.

Comment: Please read the following concerning the load event on images: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice jQuery plugin that triggers an event after all images inside an element are loaded:
http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/

See this example in Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TFVc9/2/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var image=$('#images');

    //...

   image.imagesLoaded( function() {image.slideDown(300)} );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button').click(function() {

            $('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/home.jpg" />')
            $('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/inventory.jpg" />')
            $('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/services.jpg" />')
            $('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://www.klossal.com/images/klossviolins/services.jpg" />')
            $('#theDiv').hide();

            $('#theDiv').slideDown('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```